# Python json.loads multiple callback parameters

Tags: python

I have some json that is parsed from the DB, I need to do two things.

1. Make sure order is maintained using (OrderedDict) which is build in function and cannot modify
2. Check for and rename duplicate keys which is a custom function(rename_duplicate)

```
def rename_duplicate(pairs):
        d = {}
        k_counter = Counter(defaultdict(int))
        for k, v in pairs:
            d[k+str(k_counter[k])] = v
            k_counter[k] += 1
  return d
```

How can i do use both when using json.loads?

```
json.loads(raw_text_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict,rename_duplicate)
```

Error

```
d = json.loads(row['Commands'], object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict,rename_duplicate)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Comment: Good news! If you're using a recent version of Python 3, then regular old dicts are just as ordered as OrderedDicts, and `json.loads` should return your values in the order they appear. So that's half of your problem solved right there.

Comment: @Kevin unfortunately our server runs python2.7 and no plans of upgrading

Comment: Curses! Well, I guess an OrderedDict approach is still viable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with amrx that `object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict,rename_duplicate` is not the right syntax to get what you want. It kind of looks like you're trying to tell the function that `object_pairs_hook` should return an OrderedDict and it should call `rename_duplicate`. But you can't give two values to one parameter like that*. I don't think it's necessary to specify OrderedDict here, as long as that's what you return from `rename_duplicates`.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

def rename_duplicates(pairs):
    d = OrderedDict()
    c = Counter()
    for k,v in pairs:
        new_k = k + str(c[k])
        d[new_k] = v
        c[k] += 1
    return d

s = '{"foo": "bar", "foo": "qux", "troz": "zort", "foo": "coconuts"}'
print(json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=rename_duplicates))
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([('foo0', 'bar'), ('foo1', 'qux'), ('troz0', 'zort'), ('foo2', 'coconuts')])
```

(*well, you could technically pass it a tuple that contains two values, but it will still crash because this particular parameter expects a callable, and tuples aren't callable)

---

Edit: It's not clear to me from your problem description whether unique keys should also get renamed, and whether a non-unique key should be renamed the first time it's encountered. If the answer to both of these is "no", then this is achievable with a small change to the code.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

def rename_duplicates(pairs):
    d = OrderedDict()
    c = Counter()
    for k,v in pairs:
        if k not in c:
            new_k = k
        else:
            new_k = k + str(c[k])
        d[new_k] = v
        c[k] += 1
    return d

s = '{"foo": "bar", "foo": "qux", "troz": "zort", "foo": "coconuts"}'
print(json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=rename_duplicates))
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([('foo', 'bar'), ('foo1', 'qux'), ('troz', 'zort'), ('foo2', 'coconuts')])
```

Comment: Only duplicate keys should be renamed but I think you got it with the OrderedDict() in the rename_duplicates function

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your specific requirement, there is an underlying error. When we pass arguments to functions or methods in Python we cannot pass a `non keyword argument` after a keyword argument.

```
def foo(x, y=None, z=None):
   pass

// we can call foo
foo(10, 11, 12)
foo(10, 11, z=12)
foo(x=10, z=7, y=9)

// But we cannot call foo like this
foo(x=90, 12, 3)
// Once we start using a keyword argument, all arguments after that must be a keyword argument, otherwise we will have compile time error.
```

As for elimination of duplicates, I would suggest to process the result of `json.loads` to eliminate duplicates.